# Azure function Consume messages from an Event hub and POST the same to a REST API

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I want to create a Azure function using C# that will read data from the Azure Event Hub.
Azure function has a template to get the data from the Azure Event hub and but I don't know how to post the same data (JSON format) to a REST API.
I am new to C# programming hence seeking help from the community members.

Following is the code snippet that I want to update.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace PWO.Function.NS
{
    public static class EventHubTrigger
    {
        [FunctionName("EventHubTrigger")]
        public static async Task Run([EventHubTrigger("my-events", Connection = "Eventhub_recieverpolicy")] EventData[] events, ILogger log)
        {
            var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

            foreach (EventData eventData in events)
            {
                try
                {
                    string messageBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventData.Body.Array, eventData.Body.Offset, eventData.Body.Count);

                    // Replace these two lines with your processing logic.
                    log.LogInformation($"C# Event Hub trigger function processed a message: {messageBody}");
                    await Task.Yield();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // We need to keep processing the rest of the batch - capture this exception and continue.
                    // Also, consider capturing details of the message that failed processing so it can be processed again later.
                    exceptions.Add(e);
                }
            }

            // Once processing of the batch is complete, if any messages in the batch failed processing throw an exception so that there is a record of the failure.

            if (exceptions.Count > 1)
                throw new AggregateException(exceptions);

            if (exceptions.Count == 1)
                throw exceptions.Single();
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know what changes I have to do in application configuration files such as **host.json** and **function.json**

Comment: Please add what you tried and where it *didn't* work. Please refer to [ask].  On-topic: The answer to this question is [easily searchable](https://www.google.com/search?q=consume+web+api+C%23+.net+core).

Comment: @rickvdbosch as of now I am able to get the data from an Eventhub but I do not know how do I post same message to REST API. I am fairly new to .net world. Looking for the solution specific to azure functions. thanks